# Does $\mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )=\mathbb Q(\alpha ,\beta )$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Does $\mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )=\mathbb Q(\alpha ,\beta )$ ?

I recall that $EF=\{ef\mid e\in E, f\in F\}$. It's clear that $\mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )\subset \mathbb Q(\alpha ,\beta )$, but the reverse inclusion looks correct too. I tryied with concret example, and it looks to work, so may be it's equal... But if we make the distinction, it can't be the case. So do you have an example where it doesn't work ? And under which condition the equality hold ?

Comment: I guess for general $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb R$ $\alpha^2+\beta^2\not\in \mathbb Q(\alpha)\mathbb Q(\beta)$. But obvoiusly, for $\alpha\in\mathbb Q(\beta)$ your assumption holds.

Comment: Since $1\in \mathbb Q(\beta )$, $\alpha ^2=\alpha ^2\cdot 1\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$. Same for $\beta^2\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$. Then $\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$, no ? @GyroGearloose

Comment: No, but there may be a different interpretation of $\mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$. I interpret it as $\{xy\;| x\in\mathbb Q(\alpha) \;\mbox{and}\; \mathbb y\in Q(\beta)\}$, which doesn't necessitate $\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$ is a field, $xy\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$ and $uv\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$ implies $xy+uv\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$... so $\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\in \mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$ (I think). @GyroGearloose

Comment: Why should $\mathbb Q(\alpha )\mathbb Q(\beta )$ be a field, especially why should it be closed under addition?

Comment: Ordinarily, if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are extensions of a field $F$, both contained in a larger field $\Omega$, $K_1K_2$ is defined to be the smallest field containing both; equivalently, the intersection of all fields containing both. It will rarely, if ever, be the set of products, one factor from $K_1$ and one factor from $K_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$EF$ as you've defined it is not a field in general - it is not necessarily closed under addition.

For example, is $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$?

Solve: $$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{3})=ac + bc\sqrt{2}+ad\sqrt{3}+bd\sqrt{6},$$ we know $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, so this means $ac=bd=0$ and $bc=ad=1$. Show that is not possible.

Comment: I thought it was a field, that's why I had mistakes to understand. Thanks a lot for your answer. But if it is a field, does the equality hold ?

Comment: Yes, and if you defined  $EF$ to be the smallest field containing all products, then you would have that they were the same.

Comment: So $EF=\{xy\mid x\in E, y\in F\}$ is not entirely the correct definition and should be defined as the smallest field that contain $E$ and $F$ ? (because in an exercice of mine, for $E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ and $F=\mathbb Q(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]2)$, it's written $[EF:\mathbb Q]\neq [E:\mathbb Q][F:\mathbb Q]$ but we didn't proved that $EF$ was a field... so maybe we suppose that it is... what do you think ?

Comment: @MSE The definition of $EF$ should be $\{\sum_i x_i y_i \mid x_i\in E, y_i \in F\}$ or the smallest field containing $\{ef \mid x\in E,y\in F\}$, both of which are equivalent to defining it to be the smallest field containing both $E$ and $F$.  If you are using a textbook that defines it otherwise, it is likely to be an error. (it is also possible that the author does not intend for $EF$ to be a field in general, but in my opinion this is substantially less likely)

Comment: Even that's not enough to necessarily get a field, unless $E$ and $F$ only contain algebraic numbers. For example, what is the multiplicative inverse of $e+\pi$. @Slade

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, of course.  This is an artifact of my having first learned field theory for finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.